# C project for fun

Tags: c

I am new to coding (I just started this year), so please forgive me for any dumb mistakes. However, my goal is to make some straightforward code to have users enter their username and password. I would like the username to have 8 characters,1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit, and 1 symbol. I thought my code was good but I keep running into an issue where I keep getting an error that says, "array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer". If you can find where I can improve, and what the issue might be it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char username[20];
char password[20];

bool verify_password(char *password)
{
    int length = strlen(password);

    if (length < 8) return false;

    bool has_upper = false;
    bool has_lower = false;
    bool has_digit = false;
    bool has_symbol = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(password[i])) has_upper = true;
        if (islower(password[i])) has_lower = true;
        if (isdigit(password[i])) has_digit = true;
        if (ispunct(password[i])) has_symbol = true;
    }

    if (!has_upper) return false;
    if (!has_lower) return false;
    if (!has_digit) return false;
    if (!has_symbol) return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    printf("please enter your new username:\n");
    scanf("%s", username);

    printf("please enter your password(must be 8 characters,1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit, and 1 symbol):\n");
    scanf("%s", password);
    char password[strlen(password)] = password;
    bool result = verify_password(password);
    if (result)
    {
        printf("password has been verified\n");
    }
    else
        printf("missing element described");

    printf("welcome to your account %s!, your password is %s", username, password);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message, which includes the line in the code in which the error is occurring.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read with consistent indentation.

Comment: only [error I see](https://godbolt.org/z/TaPE9YG76) is _variable-sized object may not be initialized_ at the `char password[strlen(password)] = password;` line

Comment: You've got two `password`s.. very confusing. Also, `char password[strlen(password)] = password;` isn't how you copy a string in C, if that's what you're trying to do,, use [`strcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) instead.

Comment: Your question would be of higher quality of you provided a [mre] of the problem. It is probably possible to reproduce the error using only a few lines of code. That way, your question has a higher chance of being useful for other people.

Comment: Avoid using global variables. Declare `username` and `password` only inside the `main` method. You should also use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to store strings. You can reduce the number of `return` in `verify_password` by: `return has_upper && has_lower && ...`

Comment: Maybe you can just remove the line `password[strlen(password)] = password;` ...

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is saying that arrays need to be initialized with `= { ... };`

`char password[strlen(password)]` is an array, specifically a variable-length array (VLA). However, these arrays are special since they cannot get initialized at all. You have to set their values at run-time

Furthermore, it has to be `char password[strlen(password)+1]` so there's room for the null terminator.

Furthermore, you need to assign a value to a string using `strcpy`, not with the `=` operator.

Furthermore, you cannot have several variables with the same name. Or well you can, but in case of `char password[strlen(password)] = password;`, the `password` refers to the local variable, not the global one. It's a bad idea to use global variables in general and this would be one of many reasons why.

Overall you cannot do C programming by trial & error. There's no "take a chance and type something that looks ok", you need to actually know what every single thing you write does and that it is valid C.